# String class- static vs Instance method

Tags: apex, static

I want to clear my understanding on when to declare a method as static or an instance method. In the apex string class itself, some methods are static like isBlank() while others are instance  method like length(). What needs to be considered when designing these methods. What are the memory considerations?

Comment: My comment is not related to this question, I can see that you have posted so many questions, members have answered you, but you didn't accept any of the answers. Are those answers not solving your purpose? Accepting the answers help you to increase the rep and help others to find the correct answer. That's the way SFSE community works!

Answer (score 6):

Static methods are methods that do not affect or inspect the state of an object, while instance methods are. There's no memory difference, but typically affect the size of code calling it. If you're not sure, typically look at a use case; whichever is smaller is usually correct.

For example, consider String.isBlank. Which one of these looks better?

```
1. if(someString == null || someString.isBlank()) {
2. if(someString != null && someString.isBlank()) {
3. if(String.isBlank(someString)) {
```

Clearly, using #3 is preferred, especially if you use it a lot. Since there may or may not be an object, we need to check for null first, but isBlank does that for us. However, you can't call an instance method without an instance, which means we'd be required to check for null before we could even use it, which partially defeats the purpose of it.

Next, we'll look at String.length. Which one looks better?

```
1. Integer stringLength = String.length(someString);
2. Integer stringLength = someString.length();
```

Again, while both of these are legible, #1 is kind of awkward to read, and #2 makes more sense; we know there is a String if we're checking for its length. Also, what value would we return from String.length if the string were null?

Sometimes, since we can't extend or modify library classes (e.g. Integer), we're forced to use static methods when we'd rather not (e.g. utility methods), but when we're designing our own classes, we should consider the use case and make our decision based on that. If the method should not need any data internally to operate, it's probably static. If the method modifies internal data, it should probably be an instance method.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox . A followup question. Let say a utility class contains 10 static methods. So wont all of them is loaded into memory when I call any of them? Is not it a memory issue?

Comment: @DeepSinghal The size of the class doesn't count against the heap limit, and the only "loading time" is during initial compilation of the class. While a class with one static method will compile slightly faster than one with 10, it will have no appreciable affect on CPU time, heap size limits, etc. You should avoid excessive, unnecessary static variables/static initialization blocks, but methods themselves may be as numerous as you like, assuming you don't violate other rules, like the 1MB class size limit or the 64k method size limit.

Answer (score 4):

Specifically on `isBlank`, it is static because the method is designed to handle a string reference that can be null as well as zero length (or not zero length). So it is a bit of a special case:

```
String s = null;
...
// This will work
Boolean b1 = String.isBlank(s);
// This (if the method existed) will cause a null pointer exception
Boolean b2 = s.isBlank();
```

Generally if a class has data fields and the logic of the methods is manipulating that data instance (non-static) methods have to be used; most of the methods in [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) are instance methods.

Memory considerations are rarely significant and not really related to the methods being instance or static.